# Copying data from one sheet to another workbook

Tags: excel, vba

How do I go about copying data from one file to another using VBA? When I run this code I get an error - "run-time error '1004' : application defined or object-defined error". I am using Excel 2010

```
Sub nextfile()

    Range("B5").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
    Selection.Copy
    Windows("MAIN Pivot Table.xlsx").Activate
    Range("B5").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
End Sub
```

Answer (score -1):

sure the error is because you try to copy over 2500 rows and you are using office 2003 has some limitations

Best Fix it with a loop

Range(Range("A" & ActiveCell.Row), Range("IV" & ActiveCell.Row).End(xlToLeft)).Select

To avoid this problem if the VBA macro to copy and paste a range of 2,516 rows or more rows, change the code in a loop VBA macro to copy and paste smaller ranges until data is copied and pasted the desired range.

Comment: I don't know where you get the idea that 2500 rows is a lot to copy in Excel - that is not correct.  The OP stated they are using 2010, not 2003, but even in 2003 this wasn't an issue.

Comment: just put what Microsoft http://support.microsoft.com/kb/905164/en was saying in his mistake and thought that was his problem ami I spend the same when working with excel could not spend more than 250 words in a excel filter to another